# scrollview with page control reset

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

Okay, I have a Scroll View with Page Control that works properly between 2 sections (2 pages).
So I can scroll left and right once. Is it possible to always scroll right?
Like when you get to page 2, it expands to the right, but not allowing to scroll back left.
I dont need it to simply add another page and have 3 pages then 4. at all times there should be only 2.

The reason I need this function is because I will use the scrolling to reset data. As you scroll to the right a duplicate of the interface with cleared fields will come on to the screen as the interface with the old data will go off. Its a neat way to reset, not just a boring old button.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many examples of this.  Here are a couple.

[InifiniteHorizontalScroll](https://github.com/jordim/InfiniteHorizontalScroll-iOS)

[StreetScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Hope this helps.